# Does Scala run on the JamVM

Tags: scala, jvm

Does Scala 2.8 run on the [JamVM](http://jamvm.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, it works. I just wrote a small program on it, and it was fine. Under stress I guess is a separate issue.

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason why it wouldn't, but the best way to check this is to try it out.

Comment: From the page: "JamVM is a new Java Virtual Machine conforming to the JVMspecification edition 2 (blue book)"

Answer (score 1):

Scala produces 100% valid Bytecode.

So the *real* question becomes: "Is JamVM compatible with valid Java bytecode?"

That one I can't answer, but I suspect that it is :)

Comment: real question is "will the valid jvm bytecode run fine on JVM x, y or z". It should be but is not always yes.